# Android In-app Subscriptions: Strategy for changing the subscription prize

Tags: android, google-play, subscriptions

My application receives a "product_id" from a android in-app subscription via  webserver. Users can subscribe to that product and can then consume that content. 
I published the app @Google Play - say v1.0.

Now I want to change the price of the subscription. According to https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en I can not do that:

> Note: Subscriptions must be priced greater than $0 and the price of a subscription can't be changed. Subscriptions can't be unpublished.

So I have to create a new subscription with a new "product_id". My webserver call then should receive the new "product_id". The problem is that I want that subscribers of the old subscription can still consume the content. How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you're checking if the user has a subscription you need to check both the old SKU and the new SKU. When they are getting a subscription only offer the possibility to select the new SKU.

Comment: But the user then has to update the app. If a user has an old subscription and does not update the app, the app gets the new sku from the webserver and so he is not allowed to consume. I guess I have to notify the subscribers, that they have to update...

Comment: Are you talking about subscriptions of consumable in-app purchases? They are two different things.

Comment: no, monthly subscriptions. If a user is subscribed, he has access to a premium radio stream.

Comment: Ok, without knowing how you currently validate that the user has a subscription I can't give a more specific answer than my first comment.

Comment: Validation: the problem is that i have no "hardcoded" sku in my code, but I get one sku over a webservice call. So when the webserver gives me the new sku - the app checks if a user is subscribed to the new sku.  Users of the old sku then can not access the stream.

Comment: Then make the webserver return both the old and new SKU maybe?

Comment: yeah, I thought about that.... The webserver returns a json. We could integrate the new sku via a new json field, but then I also have to update the app. What I do not want is that users with the old app version can still subscribe to the old sku....